# how do you perfom subtraction for times vectors in R

Tags: r

I am trying to perform subtraction from threshold value and time value. Both vectors are as times data type from chron library.

section 1

```
dput(time)
structure(0.685162037037037, format = "h:m:s", class = "times")
dput(threshold)
structure(0.753472222222222, format = "h:m:s", class = "times")
```

when threshold is greater then time, it works as follows:

```
threshold-time
[1] 01:38:22
```

section 2

But when the time is greater than threshold value, I get some fraction number as follows:

```
dput(time)
structure(0.83318287037037, format = "h:m:s", class = "times")
dput(threshold)
structure(0.753472222222222, format = "h:m:s", class = "times")

threshold-time
[1] -0.07971065
```

I need to be able to get the same type of results as section 1. Any ideas how could this work. Is there any way to format the results in section 2 in terms of %H:%M:%S?

Comment: If you do `time-threshold
#[1] 01:54:47`, which gives the difference between the two events in the `%H:%M:%S`.  If you don't know beforehand, which one would be larger, try  `pmax(time, threshold)- pmin(time, threshold)`

Answer (score 0):

We can wrap with `abs` and get the `%H:%M:%S` format

```
abs(threshold-time)
#[1] 01:54:47

threshold-time
#[1] -0.07971065
```

If we do the reverse

```
time-threshold
#[1] 01:54:47
```